# How to customize a bottom navigation bar in flutter with floating action button and and also curve design to the left and right?

Tags: flutter

[I am trying to achieve something like the bellow picture. But not getting the accurate design.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IXbU.png)

[I designed this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5izU.jpg)

Here is the code that i used

```
Paint paint = new Paint()
  ..color = Colors.white
  ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

Path path = Path();
path.moveTo(0, 15); // Start
path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.20, 0, size.width * 0.40, 0);
path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.40, 0, size.width * 0.40, -5);
path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.60, 0),
    radius: const Radius.circular(20.0), clockwise: false);
path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.60, 0, size.width * 0.62, 0);
path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.80, 0, size.width, 15);
path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
path.lineTo(0, size.height);
path.lineTo(0, 20);
canvas.drawShadow(path, Colors.black, 5, true);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Comment: If you could share the code snippet. It would be helpful to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Bottom Nav Bar V2',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: BottomNavBarV2(),
    );
  }
}

class BottomNavBarV2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavBarV2State createState() => _BottomNavBarV2State();
}

class _BottomNavBarV2State extends State<BottomNavBarV2> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  setBottomBarIndex(index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(55),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Container(
              width: size.width,
              height: 80,
              child: Stack(
                overflow: Overflow.visible,
                children: [
                  CustomPaint(
                    size: Size(size.width, 80),
                    painter: BNBCustomPainter(),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    heightFactor: 0.6,
                    child: FloatingActionButton(backgroundColor: Colors.orange, child: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket), elevation: 0.1, onPressed: () {}),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: size.width,
                    height: 80,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.home,
                            color: currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey.shade400,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setBottomBarIndex(0);
                          },
                          splashColor: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.restaurant_menu,
                              color: currentIndex == 1 ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey.shade400,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setBottomBarIndex(1);
                            }),
                        Container(
                          width: size.width * 0.20,
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.bookmark,
                              color: currentIndex == 2 ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey.shade400,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setBottomBarIndex(2);
                            }),
                        IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.notifications,
                              color: currentIndex == 3 ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey.shade400,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setBottomBarIndex(3);
                            }),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BNBCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 20); // Start
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.20, 0, size.width * 0.35, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.40, 0, size.width * 0.40, 20);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width * 0.60, 20), radius: Radius.circular(20.0), clockwise: false);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.60, 0, size.width * 0.65, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.80, 0, size.width, 20);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, 20);
    canvas.drawShadow(path, Colors.black, 5, true);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Try this.

Credits: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ToqYMSnNhA

Comment: I watched the video and followed the code and customized a bit. But not accurate.